# Python pandas concatenate all tsv files from directory to new file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to do a concatenate a couple hundred files in one directory and write that into a new file in a separate directory. The underlying files each have a header row. The headers in each file are expected to have the same number, name, and position based upon how the data is generated. This is the code I'm using:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
#set working directory
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user.name\\Desktop\\CombineTSV\\source\\")

#find all tsv files in the working directory
#using glob pattern matching -> extension = 'tsv'
#save result in list -> all_filenames
extension = 'tsv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all tsv files in the list
combined_file = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], sep='\t')

#set output directories, output file name
outdir = "C:\\Users\\user.name\\Desktop\\CombineTSV\\output\\"
outfile = "combined_output.tsv"

#export to tsv
combined_file.to_csv( "outdir"+"outfile", sep='\t', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

and instead of my desired output file, I'm getting this error about tokenizing data:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combinetsv.py", line 16, in <module>
    combined_file = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], sep='\t')
  File "combinetsv.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    combined_file = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], sep='\t')
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 875, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 4, saw 5
```

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to using pandas. What am I missing here?

Comment: you have to do the work of looping over the files and identifying the one that's causing trouble, then fix/handle the formatting discrepancy. my guess is you need to handle a quoted comma in a string, e.g. if your file uses single quotes but you're using the default double-quotes. see the arguments to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: My tsv files have 20 headers, but this error was only flagging 4 fields... the error feels off. Turns out the data in one of my headers contains text with four commas (I suspect one file has more!). I've indicated that tabs should be used as separators on all of my functions - why might this be occurring?

Comment: ahh - I see an issue - your `sep='\t'` is an argument to `pd.concat`, but it should be an argument to `pd.read_csv`

Comment: Ah-ha! That got it to write a file! I changed the line to this: `combined_file = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t') for f in all_filenames])` and it writes a file now... but it's writing as a csv using the column that has data with commas in it as separators. Some progress, but seems like this line may also have a syntax issue I'm not seeing: 
`combined_file.to_csv(outdir+outfile, sep='\t', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: Issue appears to be with `encoding='utf-8-sig'` and just general Excel weirdness. The combined file headers had proper tabs as long it was opened in a text editor. If it was opened in Excel, it was displaying the header row as if all the tabs were removed, so it looked like one big header instead of 20. Changing to `encoding='utf-8'` seems to have resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your tsv files, in some row, the format is wrong. That row has 5 values, but expect 4 values, so the error message is shown.
If you only want 4 values and ignore the exception value, you can use param `usecols` to set the cols you want.

```
combined_file = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], usecols=range(0,4), sep='\t')
```

Comment: Argh. I was hoping that was not the case. An unexpectedly deviant tab somewhere in the data is messing with me! :) I can't really drop any of it, so I guess I'll have to dig through them and find it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't want drop any data, I think you have to check and modify data file, it make much time to fix it (if data has many error row). I think you have to read and print index of error row, before exception is shown, and open file to see what is error.